# Como colocar imagem e texto na mesma célula do DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

Como colocar imagem e texto na mesma célula do DataGridView C#? Estou precisando que os dois sejam exibidos na mesma célula.

Comment: É DataGrid mesmo ou é DataGridView?

Comment: É no DataGridView

Comment: Não posso responder agora mas veja se isto te ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26379696/221800

Comment: Ok, Deu certo. Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você terá que criar uma classe que lide com isto. Provavelmente não vale o esforço de fazer de novo o que alguém já fez, então vou deixar aqui o que encontrei no SO [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26382753/221800).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace TradeGrid { //os nomes não precisam ser estes apresentados
public class TextAndImageColumn : DataGridViewTextBoxColumn {
    private Image imageValue;
    private Size imageSize;

    public TextAndImageColumn() {
        this.CellTemplate = new TextAndImageCell();
    }

    public override object Clone() {
        TextAndImageColumn c = base.Clone() as TextAndImageColumn;
        c.imageValue = this.imageValue;
        c.imageSize = this.imageSize;
        return c;
    }

    public Image Image {
        get { return this.imageValue; }
        set {
            if (this.Image != value) {
                this.imageValue = value;
                this.imageSize = value.Size;
                if (this.InheritedStyle != null) {
                    Padding inheritedPadding = this.InheritedStyle.Padding;
                    this.DefaultCellStyle.Padding = new Padding(imageSize.Width,
                 inheritedPadding.Top, inheritedPadding.Right,
                 inheritedPadding.Bottom);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private TextAndImageCell TextAndImageCellTemplate {
        get { return this.CellTemplate as TextAndImageCell; }
    }
    internal Size ImageSize {
        get { return imageSize; }
    }
}

public class TextAndImageCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell {
    private Image imageValue;
    private Size imageSize;

    public override object Clone() {
        TextAndImageCell c = base.Clone() as TextAndImageCell;
        c.imageValue = this.imageValue;
        c.imageSize = this.imageSize;
        return c;
    }

    public Image Image {
        get {
            if (this.OwningColumn == null || this.OwningTextAndImageColumn == null) {
                return imageValue;
            } else if (this.imageValue != null) {
                return this.imageValue;
            } else {
                return this.OwningTextAndImageColumn.Image;
            }
        }
        set {
            if (this.imageValue != value) {
                this.imageValue = value;
                this.imageSize = value.Size;
                Padding inheritedPadding = this.InheritedStyle.Padding;
                this.Style.Padding = new Padding(imageSize.Width,
                    inheritedPadding.Top, inheritedPadding.Right, inheritedPadding.Bottom);
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void Paint(Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipBounds,
    Rectangle cellBounds, int rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates cellState,
    object value, object formattedValue, string errorText,
    DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle,
    DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle,
    DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts) {
        // Paint the base content
        base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, cellState, value,
           formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, paintParts);

        if (this.Image != null) {
            // Draw the image clipped to the cell.
            System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsContainer container =
            graphics.BeginContainer();
            graphics.SetClip(cellBounds);
            graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(this.Image, cellBounds.Location);
            graphics.EndContainer(container);
        }
    }

    private TextAndImageColumn OwningTextAndImageColumn {
        get { return this.OwningColumn as TextAndImageColumn; }
    }
}
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Drawing/CustomColumn.cs).

Método para usar na célula:

```
   public void ImageRowDisplay() {
        ((TextAndImageCell)_TradeGrid.Rows[0].Cells[0]).Image = (Image)imageList1.Images[1];
     }
```

Evento para manipular a exibição:

```
    private void btnInsertData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        //Code to insert rows on the grid.
         ImageRowDisplay();
    }
```